# Header always redirect:

Tags: php, function, output

When admin log in to the admin panel it should redirect him to the admin panel and the second time to not, but it always redirecting.

```
if($logedin_admin='1'){
    $logedin_admin=0;
    $_SESSION['is_admin']=1;
    header('Location: admin/index.php');
}
```

### Can anyone tell me why?

I've made the if:

```
if(isset($logedin_admin) && $logedin_admin=='1'){
echo 'dsdasdas';
    $logedin_admin=0;
    $_SESSION['is_admin']=1;
    header('Location: admin/index.php');
    exit;
}
```

but it isn't redirecting and it isn't `echoing` dsdasdas

Comment: `=` is *assignment*, `==` is *comparison*.

Comment: That means it is not going into the `if` statement. Can you `var_dump($logedin_admin);` before the `if` and let know the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `if($logedin_admin=='1'){`

You are doing an assignment operation instead of a comparison..

Also, make sure if the session was started...

#### The code..

```
<?php
session_start();   //<=--------- Add this
if($logedin_admin=='1'){
    $logedin_admin=0;
    $_SESSION['is_admin']=1;
    header('Location: admin/index.php');
    exit; //<=----------- Add an exit too.
}
```